# How to host your virtual host in wamp?

Tags: wamp

I created a virtual host on my wampserver allowing me to access my website using the name 'testwebsite/' besides 'localhost/'. I would like users remotely access the website using testwebsite as the url rather than type the ipaddress.

Comment: Not possible without additional user actions as this DNS is unknown for rest of the world. In order to access your website trough such URL, each user must add additional record in his host file with your IP and hostname.

Comment: remotely meaning on your local network? if so, read answer above, or simply bind your Apache to your local IP, so that people can access your site on that IP, if you have multiple virtualhosts you can bind them to different ports of your machine, so that users will access your sites like http://192.168.1.200:80/ http://192.168.1.200:81/ or whatever port/ip you choose.

Comment: You need to register and pay for the hostname and set the DNS lookup of your host to the IP you need accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Let remote users change their host file:
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
and add a rule:

```
192.168.1.1 testwebsite
```

where the ip address is your address

If you want it to be automatically, you would have to install a DNS server or use an A-record from a domain you already own.

E.g. I have a domain, say example.com. In my webhosting I added an A-record test.example.com. to ip my external ip address. You can check your external ip address at [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com). Then you need to change your router configuration. Look for something like port forwarding or (in my case) port mapping and forward external port 80 to your pc in your local network.

Comment: Asker needs other users to remotely access his locally hosted website so this wont work unless he convinces all users to do this.